# Set properties of an aggregate root child

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I read an article about DDD saying that Aggregate should be responsible for creating or updating Aggregate Root Child. My only concern with this is that, what if child aggregate has a lot of property.

What I normally do is that

```
public class Parent
{

    public Child Child1{ get; protected set; }
    public void SetOrUpdateChild(string prop1, string prop2, string prop3, string prop4, string prop5, string prop6, string prop7, string prop8, string prop9, string prop10)
    {
        Child1 = Child.Create(prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, prop5, prop6, prop7, prop8, prop9, prop10);
    }
}
public class Child
{
    public Child(string prop1, string prop2, string prop3, string prop4, string prop5, string prop6, string prop7, string prop8, string prop9, string prop10)
    {
        Prop1 = prop1;
        Prop2 = prop2;
        Prop3 = prop3;
        Prop4 = prop4;
        Prop5 = prop5;
        Prop6 = prop6;
        Prop7 = prop7;
        Prop8 = prop8;
        Prop9 = prop9;
        Prop10 = prop10;
    }

    public string Prop1 { get; protected set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; protected set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; protected set; }
    public string Prop4 { get; protected set; }
    public string Prop5 { get; protected set; }
    public string Prop6 { get; protected set; }
    public string Prop7 { get; protected set; }
    public string Prop8 { get; protected set; }
    public string Prop9 { get; protected set; }
    public string Prop10 { get; protected set; }

    public static Child Create(string prop1, string prop2, string prop3, string prop4, string prop5, string prop6, string prop7, string prop8, string prop9, string prop10)
    {
        return new Child(prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, prop5, prop6, prop7, prop8, prop9, prop10);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I know I can just pass a Child object to AddChild method but I think that is not the ideal way. My concern is that it will be hard to manage if the Child object grow.

Comment: Then use a construction object, however this really is not a good fit for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Builder pattern for construction.

Additionally you could evaluate to group your parameters in meaningful Value Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with abstractions, you didn't find them. Cohesion is probably broken. Investingate how prop1 is related to prop2 and if that relation is the same for the props.If not, they should be grouped together to form a new ValueObject (Street, City, Apt --> Address)